# Make histogram of every column of a matrix but without zero elements

Tags: matlab, histogram, matlab-figure

I'm running a simulation of particles in a box. When a particle leaves the box, its kinetic energy becomes zero (for time > t escape). So I want to make a histogram of how Wkinet (which is a function of nP=number of particles, ntM=time steps) evolves through time, but I do not want to take into account the zero values of every column. Is there a way to code it so it can find the optimum number of bins?

This is what I've tried:

```
nbins = 1000;
for j = 1:ntM/5
    Wkinet(Wkinet==0) = NaN;
    y = Wkinet(:,j).*erg2eV;
end
histfit(y,nbins)
```

[image: here]

Comment: Why not make a histogram including zeros and then just remove that bin?

Comment: How could i do that? Also one problem is that it only shows me the last histogram for the final j how could i solve this and make it show all the histograms in one plot? Thank you in advance

Comment: Try not overwriting `y` every loop iteration.

Comment: Can you explain how i could to ths please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logical indexing is often rather fast and intuitive once you get the hang of the syntax.

```
myTolerance=1e-7; % in erg units.
nbins=1000;
for j=1:ntM/5
    %Wkinet(Wkinet==0)=NaN;
    % y=Wkinet(:,j).*erg2eV; % An extra assigment is costly and probably not needed.
    H = histfit(Wkinet(abs(Wkinet(:,j))>myTolerance, j) * erg2ev, nbins);
    % Select from column j all rows in column j whose absolute values are greater than the tolerance. 
    % Assumption; erg2ev is just a scalar, otherwise select its entries with erg2ev(abs(Wkinet(:,j))>myTolerance)
    H(1).delete; Remove bins, only keep the fit.
    set(gca, 'YScale', 'log'); % Make logarithmic Y
    set(gca, 'XScale', 'log'); % Make logarithmic X
    pause
end
```

If you need explicit limiting of axis, use

```
xlim([lowerBound upperBound]); ylim(etc...
```

... or sometimes it is helpful to make use of the axis command for precise control, e.g.

```
ax=axis; ax(3)=min( 8ax(3) maxAllowedY]); axis(ax);
```

The "pause" (for interactive use) may be replaced by a print command to save plots to disk. E.g.

```
print(sprintf('My_plot_%02d',j),'-dpng');
```

Or save the figure:

```
savefig(sprintf('My_fig_%02d',j));
```

If are sure that number of plots are less than, say 16, you could put a subplot command in the loop. Replace the pause by

```
subplot(4,4,j);
```

Final note; if your intent is to plot a normal distribution fitted to your nonzero data you may get better results replacing the histfit function using

```
myFit = fitdist(Wkinet(Wkinet(:,j)>myTolerance, j) * erg2ev), 'Normal');
maxEv = max(Wkinet(Wkinet(:,j)>myTolerance, j) * erg2ev);
myX   = [myTolerance; maxEv/100; maxEv]; % Alter for different plot X-axis
myY   = pdf(myFit, myX);
plot(myX, myY);
```

I checked and there *is* a difference between the fitdist and histdist, probably caused by the bin discretization.

Comment: thank you !could you also help me make the plot look like this ...i mean to only show the fit and not the bars ,be nornilized on y axis ,and have the same limits on x axis i ve added the picture in the initial question  ? @ErikP

Comment: Updates with how you remove plots, how to rescale to log-axis and how to limit scales. Unclear what kind of normalization you are after on a PDF plot. Potentially you could check the YData of H(2) for further manipulation.

Comment: Added a note on the `fitdist` function, which is probably more accurate for what you are doing.

Comment: Thank you very much!Although the second one is not working (it has an unbalanced sentence and did you want to say pdf in myY? ..What i meant about the y axis is that i want to to show percentage and going from zero to 1. @ErikP

Comment: @nikos, yes pdf is what I meant, edited. Did not see where impalance was though. I'm not sure what percentage you're after. If it is % of maximum density you could just scale by dividing with max(myY).